Networks created with python and networkx vs cypher and neo4j?
How does using flask, sqlight, networkx and sqlalchemy to create, store and load networks compare using neo4j, cypher with python for ease of use and speed?
So far it seems much easier to go with the former than the latter in terms of coding, but I don't know how slow the performance would be compared to going with near 4j and cypher.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
